# Callback-driven Spring Cloud Dataflow source application

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to create a Spring Cloud Dataflow source application based on a lib that connects to a messaging service (IRC, actually) and calls my callback when a message arrives. The only goal of the source app is to create an SCDF message from the received IRC message and send it to the stream.

I have come up with the following solution:

The `IrcListener` class annotated with `@Component` does some configuration and starts listening for IRC messages when the `start()` method is called. When a message is received its `onGenericMessage` callback simply sends the message to the stream via the injected `source` property:

```
@Component
public class IrcListener extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onGenericMessage(GenericMessageEvent event) {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.content = event.getMessage();

            source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg).build());
    }

    private Source source;
    private String _name;
    private String _server;
    private List<String> _channels;

    public void start() throws Exception {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder()
                            .setName(_name)
                            .addServer(_server)
                            .addAutoJoinChannels(_channels)
                            .addListener(this)
                            .buildConfiguration();

            PircBotX bot = new PircBotX(configuration);
            bot.startBot();
    }

    @Autowired
    public IrcListener(Source source) {
            this.source = source;

            _name = "ircsource";
            _server = "irc.rizon.net";
            _channels = Arrays.asList("#test".split(","));
    }
}
```

The main class runs Spring Application and calls the aforementioned `start()` method on the `IrcListener` component.

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class IrcStreamApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(IrcStreamApplication.class, args);
        context.getBean(IrcListener.class).start();
    }
}
```

This works ok and the messages are received and published to the stream successfully, but I'd like to know whether this is the right approach to take in the Spring (Cloud Dataflow) universe and or maybe I am missing something important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks ok; but, generally, message-driven sources extend `MessageProducerSupport` and call `sendMessage(Message<?>)`.

(and override `doStart()` in this case).

It would give you access to message history tracking and error handling (if the send fails).

Comment: thank you! But is it safe to call my `bot.startBot();` (it goes to an infinite event-listening loop) in the `doStart()` method of a `MessageProducerSupport` subclass?

Comment: No, not if it blocks, it would stop the app from starting. You would need to use a `TaskExecutor` to run it on .a different thread; `doStart()` is called on the `main` thread. What is calling `start()` now?

Comment: Currently I call it in `main` of the application - you can see the last meaningful code line in the question.

Comment: Based on your comment I think I should reimplement my `IrcListener` to extend `MessageProducerSupport` and throw in a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` (since I only need one thread) and run the `bot.startBot()` there, invoking this from `doStart()`. Does it sound right?

Comment: Yes, that would be consistent with other message driven sources.

Comment: The way you did it is ok because it's after the context starts. With MPS, start is called while the context is loading, unless you set autoStartup to false.